# checkbox keep giving error message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I keep getting javascript alert error message when submitting form even when checkbox is check?

Here is my part of my form

```
<form onsubmit="return false" action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off" id="register_form">

<div class="form-check">
 <label for="field_terms" class="form-check-label">
   <input class="form-check-input" id="field_terms" type="checkbox" name="terms" value="check" required> By clicking on "<span style="color: orange">Create a free account</span>", I agree to the ...  <a href="terms_of_service.php"> Terms of Service </a> and <a href="privacy_policy.php"> Privacy Policy</a>.
  </label>
</div>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="submit" role="button" onclick="send()" value="Create account" />

</form>
```

javascript found in my form

```
<script>
function send(){
var term = document.getElementById("field_terms").value;

if(!term.checked) {
   alert("Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions");

  } else {

        var parameters="field_terms="+term;

        var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();

        ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
                alert(ajax.responseText);


    }

};

        ajax.open("POST","register.php",false);
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajax.send(parameters);
    }
}

<script>
```

Here are my register.php

```
if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['submit'])){
 ...

if($_POST['field_terms'] != "check"){
    $errors[''] = "Term & condition is not check";
    exit();

 //Note: I'm not inserting this value into my db, I just need to verify is whether user check this box or not to proceed further

} else {
...
}
}
```

Why is when I click on my submit button I keep getting the javascript error message.

Comment: Use `required` attribute to handle native HTML5 form's validation and you shouldn't use `onclick` but `onsubmit` because the form can be submited without clicking the button

Comment: The required part was removed to make the alert error msg appear. When I use onsubmit my function does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if(term.checked)` statement is always `false` because the `term` variable is not an `HTMLInputElement` is actually the value of such an element. You should use:

```
var term = document.getElementById("field_terms");
```

instead of:

```
var term = document.getElementById("field_terms").value;
```